# Tomcat Active Directry authentication

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to migrate a Tomcat webapp from Tomcat 6 to 9. This app needs to authenticate users against  AD, which it successfully did in the old instance for years. The JNDI realm settings that worked on the old server are:

```
 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
        connectionURL="ldap://ourIP:389"
        alternateURL="ldap://ourIP:389"
        connectionName="cn=ourService Account,cn=Users,dc=ourDomain,dc=lan"
        connectionPassword="ourServiceAcctPW"
        referrals="follow"
        userBase="ou=ourOU,dc=ourDomain,dc=lan"
        userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
        userSubtree="true"
        roleBase="dc=ourDomain,dc=lan"
        roleName="name"
        roleSearch="(member={0})"
        roleSubtree="true"
      />
```

When I apply this config to server.xml in the new version I get the following error:

javax.naming.PartialResultException [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: ourDomain.lan:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]]

It appears that Tomcat is ignoring the connectionURL parameter. I have verified that the new server can authenticate against AD using ldapsearch.

I am thoroughly perplexed and would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Maybe it is using your `connectionURL`, but it's doing a reverse DNS lookup on the IP address at some point, and that's why it's showing you `ourDomain.lan`? Maybe look at the actual network traffic with something like Wireshark and verify the IP it's actually trying to connect to.

Comment: Thanks. I verified the IP with telnet and ldapsearch. Also, the exact same settings work for the old server.